# Anyway to get Visual Studio C++ to autocomplete parameter list?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, parameters, autocomplete, lazy-evaluation

Very specific issue with a specific piece of software, but I hope you fine folks can help!

I define a class in a header.h file that has a few method declarations that take parameters

```
class Lazy{
    void complainForever(char * complaint, float forever = INFINITY);
};
```

Then I go into the Lazy.cpp file to define that function.  Here is a psuedo timelapse of just how lazy I am.

```
void Lazy:: // <-- autocomplete kicks in, select method and hit enter

void Lazy::complainForever // <-- parameter list missing, completely defeating purpose
```

At that point, I either have to type it by hand, or copy/paste the parameter list from the header.h file

The question is this!  Is there a keyboard shortcut or any method at all for having autocomplete take care of the parameter list for me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/). It isn't free though.

Comment: Yes, Visual Assist will suggest the param list of the declaration when typing the definition.

Comment: Taking it for a whirl now.  It may very well be worth the academic price!

Answer (score -2):

Once you are done defining the class in your header file, try to update Intellisense.

Updating intellisense can be achieved by reloading your project/solution. Once your intellisense is update, when you try to implement the class definition - you get the autocomplete feature on your newly defined class enabled. This includes the individual function prototypes as defined in the header.

Answer (score -2):

Keyboard shortcut to display intellisense is **Ctrl + Space**.

Thanks